# How to pass the right cyrillic letters on server using MultiUploader in GWT?

Tags: gwt, encoding, multi-upload

I'm using MultiUploader in GWT and I wat to pass userNumber on server through servlet path.

```
MultiUploader muplDef = new MultiUploader();
muplDef.setServletPath(muplDef.getServletPath() + "?userNumber="
                + "ВАВАВАВАВ" + "&mode=" + "JPG"
                + "&hm=" + GWT.getPermutationStrongName());
```

My userNumber contains cyrillic letters "ВАВАВАВАВ" and on the server I get the wrong userNumber: ÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐ.

```
 @Override
    public String executeAction(HttpServletRequest request,
            List<FileItem> sessionFiles) throws UploadActionException {
        try {
            request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            userNumber = request.getParameter("userNumber");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
...
```

How to pass the right userNumber on server using MultiUploader in GWT? Thanks.

**EDIT**
On my local tomcat everything works great, but on server I get the wrong userNumber. Even I wrote `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` I still don't know what to do( I need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to URL-encode the parameters in your call (all or just the user number):

```
String param = URL.encode("?userNumber="
            + "ВАВАВАВАВ" + "&mode=" + "JPG"
            + "&hm=" + GWT.getPermutationStrongName());

muplDef.setServletPath(muplDef.getServletPath() + param);
```

Comment: Thank you, but for me this didn't work. On my local tomcat everything works great, but on the server tomcat cyrillic letters pass with error(

Comment: You cannot use cyrillic letters in a URL, so you must URL-encode this string in any case. You may have a problem somewhere else, but not in the code snippet that you provided. Make sure that on Tomcat the encoding is set correctly: `<Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>`